# kinect SKD skeletonization method

Tags: kinect, depth

I was wondering if there's a way to modify the depth map prior to sending it to the skeletonization algorithm used by the kinect, for example, if we want to run the skeletonization on  the output of a segmented depth image. So far I have reviewed the methods in the sdk but I haven't been able to find a skeletonization method exposed. It's like you either turn the skeleton on or off but you have no control on its inputs.
If anyone has any idea regarding this topic I will be much obliged.

Shamita: skeletonization means tracking the joints of the user in real time. I edit because I can't comment (not enought reputation).

Comment: what is this "skeletonization " you keep talking about.

Answer (score 0):

All the joints' give a depth coordinate and I don't think you can mess with the Kinect hardware input stream. But you can categorize the joints regarding to depth segments. For example with the live stream you categorize it with the corresponding category if it is below 10 and above five it is in category A. this can be done with the live stream itself because it is just a simple calculation.